# Is this sequence the Markov chain?

Tags: random-variables, markov-chains

Let $\xi_n, n\geq 1$ be a sequence of discrete random variables, $\xi_n \in A=\{1,2,...,K\}, \forall n$. This sequence satisfies the following condition:
$$P(\xi_n=i_1|\xi_m=i_2,\xi_k=i_3)=P(\xi_n=i_1|\xi_m=i_2), \forall n>m>k, i_1,i_2,i_3 \in A.$$
The question: Will this sequence be a Markov chain?
Any suggestion or example are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Which examples did you study to solve this?

Comment: @Did: Sorry, I didn't see your comment here. I just want to know the past information $\sigma(\xi_k,k<m)$ can be replaced with the information $\sigma(\xi_k)$ for every $k<m$ or not? I think that's not true but I have no idea.

Comment: Which examples did you study to solve this?

Comment: I haven't done or found anything relating to this problem except for the definition of discrete Markov chain.

Comment: What a pity. Which simple examples would you study if you wanted to gain some insights about the question? (Because you **do** want to gain some insights about the question, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\xi_n$ is adapted to the filtration $F_n$, the Markov Property is given by
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} \left( \xi_n = i_1 \mid F_{m} \right) = \mathbb{P} \left( \xi_n = i_1 \mid \xi_{m} \right), \quad \forall n>m, i_1 \in A
\end{align}
which intuitively means that the only information that is relevant for future jumps is the 
most recent information. In your example, the Markov Property is 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} \left( \xi_n = i_1 \mid \xi_m = i_2, \xi_{m-1}=i_3, \dots, \xi_1=i_{m+2} \right) = &\mathbb{P} \left( \xi_n = i_1 \mid \xi_{m} =i_2 \right), 
\\ \forall n>m, i_1 \dots i_{m+2} \in A.
\end{align}
However, this is not the property that you were given. So the sequence $(\xi_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is not Markov with the information you were given.
 Imagine that information about 3 consecutive values of $\xi$, $\xi_{n},\xi_{n-1},\xi_{n-2}$, would change the jump probabilities for $\xi_{n+1}$ compared to just having the knowledge of $\xi_n$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} \left( \xi_{n+1} = i_1 \mid \xi_n = i_2, \xi_{n-1}=i_3,\xi_{n-2}=i_{4} \right) \neq &\mathbb{P} \left( \xi_{n+1} = i_1 \mid \xi_{n} =i_2 \right), 
\\ \forall n, i_1, i_2, i_3, i_{4} \in A.
\end{align}
This example is a sequence that would not have the Markov Property, but could still have the property you were given.

**EDIT:**
Here is a more concrete example: Let $ \left(X_n \right)_{n \geq 0}$ be a sequence of discrete random variables, $X_n \in A = \{ 1,2,\dots,K  \} \forall n$, where 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} \left(X_{n+1} =a+1 \mid X_n = a \right) &= \frac{2}{3},\quad \forall n, a \in \{ 1,2,\dots,K-1  \}
\\
\mathbb{P} \left(X_{n+1} =a \mid X_n = a \right) &= \frac{1}{3},\quad \forall n, a \in \{ 1,2,\dots,K  \} 
\\
\mathbb{P} \left(X_{n+1} =1 \mid X_n = K \right) &= \frac{2}{3},\quad \forall n
\\
\mathbb{P} \left( X_{n} = a_1 \mid X_{m} =a_2 , X_k = a_3 \right) &= \mathbb{P} \left( X_{n} = a_1 \mid X_{m} =a_2 \right) \forall n, a_1, a_2, a_3 \in A
\end{align}
So far, this looks like a Markov Chain, and if no further information about sequence is given, it would be fair to assume it is a Markov Chain (ie. assuming all unspecified probabilities are $0$). Notably, it has the desried property that is given in your problem. However, if it was futhermore given that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} \left( X_{n+1} = 1 \mid X_{n} =a , X_{n-1} = a, X_{n-2} =a \right) &=1 \quad \forall n, a\in A,
\end{align}
the sequence cannot have the Markov Property (and thus cannot be a Markov Chain) despite having the property given in the problem. This is due to
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} \left( X_{n+1} = 1 \mid X_{n} =a , X_{n-1} = a, X_{n-2} =a \right) \neq \mathbb{P} \left( X_{n+1} = 1 \mid X_{n} =a \right) \quad \forall n, a\in A,
\end{align}
since we would need an equality in the equation above.

Comment: Could you explain more about your example? How to construct the sequence that satisfies not only my given condition for all $n>m>k$ but also your inequality?

Comment: "Intuitively" Sure, but the OP is (presumably) asking for a mathematical proof, and you give none.

Comment: I edited my answer. I cannot give a rigorous mathematical proof of why the initial property does not imply the Markov Property. However, I did add a counterexample.

Comment: Mstar, you should read his answer again. What you’re saying doesn’t make any sense. His assumption is perfectly valid.

Comment: I have read the answer again. Now I got it. Thank you for your help, O.T.  and @MadsHulgaard. My foolish comment above was removed.

Comment: "Here is a more concrete example" Sorry but I fail to see any description of the distribution of a specific process. To begin with, how are the conditions you give, patched together?

Comment: The distribution of the counterexample process, $\left(X_n \right)_{n\geq 0}$, is given by the first 3 probabilities after the edit. In short, the process increases in value by 1 after 1 step with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ (except for the value K, then it goes back to 1) and has the same value after 1 step with probability $\frac{1}{3}$. Given no more information and assuming all other probabilities are 0, the process would be a Markov Chain. However, adding the condition that if the process has the same value for 3 steps in a row, it goes back to 1 guaranteed, the process cannot be Markovian.